# Large image for drupal home using css injector

Tags: css, image, drupal

Based on this page :
 - http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

I have used CSS injector to make my home page :
 - http://tailored.bike/

I believe I had this code working properly

```
.front h1.title { display: none; }
body {background: none;}
html { 
    background: url(/sites/default/files/u44/framed_home_2013_10_19.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

Then for some reasons I had to change the domain name and I can't have it work back.

Does any one have an idea ?

Regards

Julien

edits:

1. Does nok work neither with full http://... image url.
2. It works if I uncheck "Preprocess CSS"... I let it this way for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in Chrome and your background image reference is still mapped to your old domain. Your CSS should read:

```
html {
  background:url(http://tailored.bike/sites/default/files/u44/framed_home_2013_10_19.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  /* Other CSS stuff */
}
```

Fix that reference and the image loads fine.